# Signing SAML2 AuthnRequest with ECDSA-SHA256 in LightSAML SP Bundle

Tags: saml-2.0, symfony4, x509, signing

In IdP definition that the bundle uses, among other things, to generate **AuthnRequest**:

HOW/WHERE do I specify that I want the `AuthnRequest` signed e.g. with **ECDSA-SHA256**?

Do I have to override a factory service to achieve that?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor
    xmlns:mdalg="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:algsupport"
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    entityID="some-entity">
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <mdalg:SigningMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
        <ds:X509Data>
```

I tried adding `mdalg:SigningMethod` and `ds:SignatureMethod`, as above, but I don't really know what I'm doing, as the config schema is not really well-defined in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your placement of mdalg:SigningMethod is wrong. It is an extension to the original SAML2 standard and as such needs to live in an  block. Take this as hearsay from me as I don't actually use that myself.

Here is the mailing list post regarding simpleSAMLphp software, and credit for the content goes to Peter Schober:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simplesamlphp/HSdZXaYUuRI/bdz7mQJLBgAJ

An example of the placement in the XML is in there.

Comment: SO ate my XML. ... needs to live in an &lt; Extensions &gt;

Comment: Extensions declares a list of available algos and I need to set a specific one to use.